# Extendable Vector Type

Tags: vector, common-lisp, adjustable-array

How does one properly specify the common-lisp type of an extendable vector (ie, acceptable to vector-push-extend), so it can be copied. For example, if a vector is defined by:

```
(defparameter v (make-array 2
                            :initial-contents '((a (b)) (c (d) e))
                            :adjustable t
                            :fill-pointer t))
```

My simple (incorrect) approach for copying it is:

```
(map 'array #'copy-tree v)
```

but this generates a type error in sbcl. Can a proper sequence type specification make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Simple copy

You could simply do this:

```
(map (type-of v) #'copy-tree v)
```

What is the type?

```
CL-USER> (type-of v)
(VECTOR T 2)
```

The following is sufficient:

```
(map 'vector #'copy-tree v)
```

[This graph](https://sellout.github.io/2012/03/03/common-lisp-type-hierarchy/) is helpful to remember type hierarchies, notably arrays and vectors.

#### Adjustable, fill-pointer, ...

However, the resulting vectors are not adjustable. Maybe something like this can help:

```
(defun my-copy (vector)
  (map-into (make-array (array-dimensions vector)
                        :adjustable (adjustable-array-p vector)
                        :fill-pointer (fill-pointer vector))
            #'copy-tree
            vector))
```

Comment: My next goto for this was the loop macro, but map-into is nicely chunked. Thanks for the type hierarchy reference also.

Answer (score 3):

`MAP` needs as a result type a *sequence type specifier*. `ARRAY` is not one. Examples for subtypes of `SEQUENCE` are `VECTOR` and `LIST`.

The type declaration syntax for a `VECTOR` is: `vector [{element-type | *} [{size | *}]]`.

There is no way to specify features like *adjustable*, *fill pointer*, *displacement*, ... in a vector type declaration. Corresponding feature options are also not provided as keywords to the function `make-sequence`. Also `copy-seq` will not create vectors with such features. To create such vectors you have to use `MAKE-ARRAY`.

Thus the options are:

- maybe the vector types are sufficient
- for vectors with special features, create them via `MAKE-ARRAY` and use functions like `MAP-INTO` -> see the excellent answer from coredump.